# Instagram Login Failure Issue

Tags: authentication, instagram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNp0o.png)

When i try to login my instagram through the web this blank screen doesn't load. Tried clearing cache and cookies on the browser but still the issue persists. On inspecting the page on console this error is displayed

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/business/account/get_web_pro_onboarding_eligibility/`

`` The resource https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/es6/FeedSidebarContainer.css/f627ebef4169.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. ``

`Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.`

Answer (score 1):

Same errors here. Feed site is empty. I can open my profile site or profiles from other users,  that is working.

See the screenshot. On the feed site is a GET request and in the status I get "429 Too Many Requests". I have no glue what is going wrong here. On my two other Instagram profiles the feed is working.

[image: GET response status]